# How do I map an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
arr = [ {:a => 1, :b => 2}, {:a => 3, :b => 4} ]
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
arr.map{|x| x[:a]}.reduce(:+)
```

but I think it's a bit ugly, or at least not that elegant as:

```
arr.map(&:a).reduce(:+)
```

The later one is wrong because there is no method called `a` in the hashes.

Are there any better ways to write `map{|x| x[:a]}`?

Comment: I think that is as good as it's going to get. I'm pretty sure hashes are not ordered in memory so it's only safe to get the keys you want.

Comment: @squiguy Hashes preserve order in Ruby 1.9 and later.

Comment: Trying to save six characters because it's a "bit ugly" is pretty questionable.

Comment: @meagar And it might be argued that it *should* be ugly, as perhaps preferring Hashes over domain objects is itself questionable, and the pervasive “bit ugliness” throughout the code is a sign of over-use of Hashes. Maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make actual Objects, possibly with a [Struct](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Struct.html):

```
MyClass = Struct.new :a, :b
arr = [MyClass.new(1, 2), MyClass.new(3, 4)]
arr.map(&:a).reduce(:+)  #=> 4
```

Or for more flexibility, an [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html):

```
require 'ostruct'
arr = [OpenStruct.new(a: 1, b: 2), OpenStruct.new(a: 3, b: 4)]
arr.map(&:a).reduce(:+)  #=> 4
```

Of course either of these can be constructed from existing hashes:

```
arr = [{ :a => 1, :b => 2 }, { :a => 3, :b => 4 }]

ss = arr.map { |h| h.values_at :a, :b }.map { |attrs| MyClass.new(*attrs) }
ss.map(&:a).reduce(:+)  #=> 4

oss = arr.map { |attrs| OpenStruct.new attrs }
oss.map(&:a).reduce(:+)  #=> 4
```

Or, for a more creative, functional approach:

```
def hash_accessor attr; ->(hash) { hash[attr] }; end
arr = [{ :a => 1, :b => 2 }, { :a => 3, :b => 4 }]
arr.map(&hash_accessor(:a)).reduce(:+)  #=> 4
```

Comment: `.map { |x| x[:a] }` remains the best by far :p

Comment: @meagar Yea, though it’s fun to explore options. My comment above echoes the first (perhaps overshadowed) clause of my answer: make objects!

Comment: @meagar Any way to rephrase that code?  I tried `.map(&:[], :propname)`, but no alterations of that are working..  I just get syntax errors, even with `:send` in there as well...  Pretzel colon!!  Probably only accepts a single parameter..

Comment: @Pysis Why would you want to rephrase this? To what end?

Comment: It just feels more concise without that `do` 'hash' block.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.7 added a shorthand block syntax where you can use `_1`, `_2` etc to access the params passed to a block, so you can do something like this:

```
arr.map { _1[:a] }.reduce(:+)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean as "better" and why you think the correct version is ugly.

Do you like this "better"?

```
arr.inject(0) { |sum, h| sum + h[:a] }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way, extending the `Symbol`.

*lib/core_extensions/symbol.rb* (credit goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23711606/6439240))

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Symbol
  def with(*args, &)
    ->(caller, *rest) { caller.send(self, *rest, *args, &) }
  end
end
```

Then, given:

```
arr = [ {:a => 1, :b => 2}, {:a => 3, :b => 4} ]
```

you can do this:

```
arr.map(&:[].with(:a)).reduce(:+)
```

**Explanation**: to access hash value under any key, you call `Hash#[]` method. When passed as a `:[]` (extended) symbol to the `Array#map`, you can then call `.with(*args)` on this symbol, effectively passing the parameter (hash key) down to the `:[]` method. Enjoy.